# Where do I find "bucket" details for Firebase setup?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

For configuring my firebase connection I need to include bucket details.

```
storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
```

Where do I find this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can find the bucket ID in the [Storage panel of your project's Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-8080059325282098184/storage/files):

[image: Storage Panel of the Firebase Console]

It's the value starting with `gs://`.

Answer (score 15):

I think that you are trying to find firebase config, aren't you?
Just open as below configuration

[image]

[image]